# Localized string with argument adds line breaks and brackets around argument

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to display a localized string that contains an argument. Instead of displaying the string in one line with the argument embedded, the result is a broken 3-line string:

Expected result:

```
The price is $9.99/year.
```

Result:

```
The price is (
    "$9.99"
)/year.
```

Localizable.strings:

```
"price_string" = "The price is %@/year.";
```

Call:

```
"price_string".localized(priceString)
```

where `priceString` is a String variable.

And `.localized()` is defined as such:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
      return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "\(self)_comment")
    }

    func localized(_ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
      return String(format: localized, args)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please look at the output. It shows clearly that the *price* argument is an array. And indeed the variadic parameter `args` is treated as an array.

So you are just using the wrong API

```
func localized(_ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
     return String(format: localized, arguments: args)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually cannot get to the definition of that String initializers. I managed to find the one you suggest using (and it works): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407827-init. But I can't find the doc for the initializer that I was using.

Comment: We are talking about Swift : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126743-init

Comment: Oh indeed. So the one I was incorrectly using is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init. I don't see any definition of what the init does/returns. Is it just that the documentation is incomplete, or are we supposed to understand this naturally?

Comment: Unfortunately many APIs in Swift seem to be incomplete. However the `String(format` APIs are actually self-explanatory.

Comment: All right. Thank you so much again for taking the time to explain all this!

Comment: I was using String(format: s, args) which also didn't work, String(format: s, arguments: args) did the job for me

Comment: Thanks, this answer probably helped me save 30mins of further debugging work :D